# I have added a port to the public zone in firewalld but still can't access the port

Tags: networking, centos7, firewalld, rhel7

I've been using iptables for a long time, but have never used [firewalld](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Security_Guide/sec-Using_Firewalls.html) until recently.
I have enabled port 3000 TCP via firewalld with the following command:

```
# firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=3000/tcp --permanent
```

However I can't access the server on port 3000. From an external box:

```
telnet 178.62.16.244 3000
Trying 178.62.16.244...
telnet: connect to address 178.62.16.244: Connection refused
```

There are no routing issues: I have a separate rule for a port forward from port 80 to port 8000 which works fine externally. My app is definitely listening on the port too:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode      PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      99         36797      18662/node
```

`firewall-cmd` doesn't seem to show the port either - **see how `ports` is empty**. You can see the forward rule I mentioned earlier.

```
# firewall-cmd --list-all
public (default, active)
  interfaces: eth0
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: port=80:proto=tcp:toport=8000:toaddr=
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

However I can see the rule in the XML config file:

```
# cat /etc/firewalld/zones/public.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<zone>
  <short>Public</short>
  <description>For use in public areas. You do not trust the other computers on networks to not harm your computer. Only selected incoming connections are accepted.</description>
  <service name="dhcpv6-client"/>
  <service name="ssh"/>
  <port protocol="tcp" port="3000"/>
  <forward-port to-port="8000" protocol="tcp" port="80"/>
</zone>
```

What else do I need to do to allow access to my app on port 3000?

Also: is adding access via a port the correct thing to do? Or should I make a firewalld 'service' for my app instead?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using the `--permanent` flag writes your changes to the persistent configuration, but not the running configuration. Run the same command again without the `--permanent` flag to have it take effect immediately.

[Beginning with RHEL 7.1](https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHBA-2015-0520.html) and current versions of Fedora, you can also copy the running configuration to the permanent configuration with:

```
firewall-cmd --runtime-to-permanent
```

Comment: I think if you use the GUI version, there is an option to copy running configuration to permanent.

Answer (score 5):

Weirdly, the rule only seemed to be written out to the config file, and not applied immediately. I had to reload the firewall:

```
firewall-cmd --reload
```

After this, the rule then showed up:

```
# firewall-cmd --zone=public --list-all
public (default, active)
  interfaces: eth0
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports: 3000/tcp
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: port=80:proto=tcp:toport=8000:toaddr=
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

The port is now accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving this note as my issue was not resolved till I restarted the systemctl with

sudo systemctl restart firewalld

I had tried all the above stuff. Rebooted the vm. I even set the rules in VNIC. But it was resolved only after restarting the service.

Environment: Oracle Cloud Network
VM: Compute Instance (Developer with Oracle Linux 8)

Comment: firewall-cmd --reload - is stated above, this is the same as you do

Answer (score -3):

a restart is required to apply the changes you made

Comment: why not writing it as comment?